# Delete from Array and return deleted elements in Ruby

Tags: arrays, ruby, select

How can I delete some elements from an array and select them?

For example:

```
class Foo 
  def initialize
    @a = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
  end

  def get_a
    return @a
  end
end

foo = Foo.new
b = foo.get_a.sth{ |e| e < 4 }
p b # => [1,2,3]
p foo.get_a # => [4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
```

What I can use instead of `foo.get_a.sth`?

Comment: Your instance variable `@a` on the class `Foo` is not doing anything. You should remove it.

Comment: Question is abstracted and detail is removed. you can suppose that line `@a = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]` is the result of a some process.

Comment: I'm sorry!! I'm used to java form!!! :p

Comment: where's the abstractFactoryFactory? jk, but seriously ruby is a different culture than java, please use clearer examples and maybe some reference to real world objects and so forth. Hard to read this.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

If you don't need to retain the object id of `a`:

```
a = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
b, a = a.partition{|e| e < 4}
b # => [1, 2, 3]
a # => [4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
```

If you do need to retain the object id of `a`, then use a temporal array `c`:

```
a = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
b, c = a.partition{|e| e < 4}
a.replace(c)
```

Comment: nice answer, but i can not change the `a`. `a` is result of a `some_object.get_some_array` function

Comment: @NewMrd Why can't you change it? A variable is a variable, so you can always assign one to be the result of that call, then this pattern works fine.

Comment: Can you not just use `a.select { |e| e < 4 }` in that case? This will return the elements that pass the test.

Comment: tanks @sawa. i used `some_object.set_some_array c` instead of `a.replace c`.

Answer (score 4):

Rails 6 now has this:

```
a = [1, 2, 3]
#=> [1, 2, 3]
a.extract! { |n| n.even? }
#=> [2]
a
#=> [1, 3]
```

Answer (score 2):

If you were only deleting one item, this doesn't require duplicating the array, etc:

```
array = [{ id: 1 }, { id: 2 }, {id: 3 }]
array.delete_at(array.find_index { |element| element[:id] == 1 })
#=> {:id=>1}
```

Comment: This is the perfect solution to my application for similar need.

Comment: this will fail if find_index returns nil

Answer (score 1):

```
a = [1, 2, 3, 4]
a.dup - (a.delete_if(&:even?))
#=> [2, 4]

a
#=> [1, 3]

a = [1, 2, 3, 4]
b = a.dup - (a.delete_if { |e| e < 4 })
a
#=> [4]
b
#=> [1, 2, 3]
```

Edit: It sounds like you are just after `#select`...

```
a = [1, 2, 3, 4]
a.select { |e| e < 3 }
#=> [1, 2]
```

Comment: If there are duplicate elements then the block would return the same for both of them so this isn't something that would be a problem!

Comment: Can you provide an example?

Answer (score 0):

I still don't believe ruby doesn't have something for this in its default libraries. There should be #drop method equivalent for this. Surely there's a gem available that would add the functionality to the array class. But who needs gems when you can just break out your own scripts:

```
#in initializer somewhere
class Array
  def exclude(obj)
    x = self
    x.delete(obj)
    x
  end
end
```

I may submit a pull request to the ruby github project for this method. This superman-patch works very well so far.