# Trying to make my first submission to the ruby project on github -- a new Array class instance method

Tags: ruby, arrays, github, open-source

I recently answered a question on this site ([Delete from Array and return deleted elements in Ruby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17973282/delete-from-array-and-return-deleted-elements-in-ruby/23143684#23143684)) so well in my opinion that while writing I decided I'd try to submit a pull request for my nifty little method that would make ruby just a bit more awesome I think.

So I have a few questions, the most pressing of which is, Where is the Array class in ruby's source code? I can't find it. If its not there, is it in another repository that I should commit to? Or should I add it somewhere else in some initializer?

Where do new array methods like `#uniq` and `#drop` get added? Because I have a new one. `#exclude`.

To put it one way, #exclude is to #delete as #drop is to #shift. Just as #shift *returns* what has been removed from the array, so does #delete. #exclude is supposed to be like #drop for #delete. Extremely simple. Seems to work well.

```
class Array
  def exclude(obj)
    x = self
    x.delete(obj)
    x
  end
end
```

I may also add a #pop equivalent for #drop, #popdrop or #backdrop. Am open to suggestions

```
class Array
  def drop(n) #drop could have been implemented like this.
    x = self
    x.shift(n)
    x
  end

  def popdrop(n)
    x = self
    x.pop(n)
    x
  end
end
```

**I'm supposed to be working right now so don't have much time to edit this question. Mods let me know if I need to add more detail to the question -- specifically I just don't know where to put it. I've already forked the repo and am trying to just make a commit on github, which you can do now, but don't know where to put the code, or even if I should actually make a pull request at this point (sandbox?, IRC?, etc).**

Answer (score 1):

Ruby is coded in the language C for performance.
https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/trunk/array.c

You may be better off creating a gem, or writing a blog about it.

Otherwise you can write your Array deletion method in C. Here is the actual deletion method to help out.
https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/trunk/array.c#L2919

Comment: I'd agree with "You may be better off creating a gem, or writing a blog about it." - I doubt that changes to Ruby language are considered simply via direct pull requests to MRI Ruby (which is nowadays just one implementation of the language).

Comment: Agreed, I could image bureaucracy of random pull request **array.c**